# Galaxy note 1 taking resources from mdpi

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

Ok so I'm a bit confused here...

I have an android application referencing different icons based on screen density.
The folders I have are as follows:

drawable-hdpi 
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-normal-notlong-mdpi
drawable-xhdpi

When testing on Galaxy Note 2, the application renders graphics correctly from the XHDPI folder.
However, when I saw on it on a friend's device running on Galaxy Note 1, it displays very small icons, probably from normal-notlong-mdpi folder.

I cannot understand why this is happening, and I can't experiment too much as I don't have a Galaxy Note 1 device.

Based on that, I have two questions:

1- Why is that happening and how to overcome it?
2- How can I emulate a Galaxy Note 1 device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'm answering my own question...

It turns our Galaxy takes  One was getting resources from drawable-normal-notlong-mdpi. 
It is similar to Nexus 4 in the Emulator.

The reason is probably because notlong takes precedence over the ppi. So when I removed the folder drawable-normal-notlong-mdpi, Galaxy Note One and Nexus 4 started reading from the xhdpi normally.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Dpi is a physical feature. Since the system cannot know the screen size and the resolution by itself. This character is configured manually.

Dpi is set in the /system/build.prop and sometimes vendor would like to set a special dpi for special reasons. For example Nexus S is really mdpi while it is set to hdpi.

To emulate Note One, you can customize a device with the same solution and dpi.

Sent from my cell phone, sorry for any typo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but why is Note One taking the resources from MDPI, while it should be HDPI or even XHDPI?

Comment: Maybe it wants to display small icon and make a large screen effect.